# Toggle elements with class except for $(this).next()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an accordion effect with a nested unordered list.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('.open').toggle();
        active = $(this).next().toggle();
        active.addClass('open');
    });
});
</script>
```

With the above code I know that it closes everything with a class of "open", and I know why, but I wish to add code to skip over the element indicated in the variable "active".

Here's my full code if that helps:

```
<style>

ul {
    display:none;
}


</style>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('.open').toggle();
        active = $(this).next().toggle();
        active.addClass('open');
    });
});
</script>


<a href="#" id="toggle">toggle menu</a>
<ul id="menu">
<li>
    <a href="#">cool 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">cool 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>hey 1</li>
                <li>hey 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">cool 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li>hey 1</li>
                <li>hey 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">cool 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">cool 2</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="#">cool 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">cool 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>hey 1</li>
                <li>hey 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">cool 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">cool 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you want the accordion to collapse when you "close" on the menu item by clicking again? probably yes.    do you want the sub-items to remember their state or to be reset (collapsed) when you "close/reopen" a super-item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $ul = $this.next().toggle().addClass('open');
        $('.open').not($this.parents().add($ul)).hide().removeClass('open')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ztKkr/)

Comment: winner winner, chicken dinner

Answer (score 2):

You can use [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to skip the element in your selector.

Comment: They will always be in different list items, sometimes farther apart than other times. So I'm pretty sure that won't work, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bPGNE/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $ul = $this.next().toggle().toggleClass('open');
        $('.open').not($this.parents().add($ul)).hide()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the code short-and-sweet. I'll assume that you want the sub items to remember their state.

Secondly, I'll throw in a bonus tip that you should use a delegated handler. This will help code maintenance if you decide to add menus dynamically.  i put it on `body` here, but you probably want to define / use some kind of wrapping `div` or equivalent

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/ztKkr/6/)

```
$('body').on('click','a', function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggleClass('open');
});
```